# Ubuntu Auto Connect to Wifi

Tags: ubuntu, internet, wireless-networking, connection

Altho' I have marked several access points to "Auto connect", Ubuntu still doesn't connect automatically so many times (sometimes it does).

Is there any setting change that I need to do.

This is particularly a problem because, any windows machine auto connects whenever the wifi is available; One can easily assume a connected PC all the time, when in range. Its a huge distraction, one that can easily be done away with, to have to look if the PC is connected each time you log on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try using an alternate wifi manager. I've heard good things about [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/). But that's more of a suggestion than an answer, I've never used anything other than the default in Ubuntu.

Comment: Network Manager has always performed very poorly for me in Ubuntu. I finally switched to wicd on my eeepc and my laptop and it performs beautifully.